# stop an looping animation on hover and click to start it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the link below there are some bubbles wich animates from left to right in a loop. If you hover over one of them, it gets larger and stops animating. My problem is that the bubble doesnt stop for very long, I want it to stop permanently, until you click on it

http://jsfiddle.net/jukke/SU4gJ/1/

You are also more than welcome to rewrite parts of the code to make it better/cleaner. I dont really have much experience coding :)